# Activities are not showing under Activities tab in contact record

Tags: activities

I'm not sure exactly when this happened but the activity list has stopped showing up in the Activities tab for all of my contact records. The number of activities seems to be accurate and I can add activities but they simply do not show up.

I ran patched the Activities.php file and unchecked 'Enable CiviMail to create activities on delivery' as per [this](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=31810.0) page. I also emptied the contents of template_c and then emptied the Drupal cache but none of the steps helped.

I'm running Drupal 7 and CiviCRM 4.4.3. Any thoughts on what might be happening?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you start by upgrading to the latest version of CiviCRM 4.4. That one is quite old and has security issues as well.

Answer (score 0):

do you have any JavaScript error? check on the developer console (firebug or the native one from your browser)

But as Coleman suggested: you need to update your civi asap, it is unprotected and you might end up having the list of your contacts hacked and published publicly, I'm sure something you do not want to happen.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I guess I have a CiviCRM upgrade coming soon.